# Run JUnit test from command line

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I am a newbie in automation testing and in JUnit and I have a little question for you.
I have read a lot of materials but nothing helped me.
I have a task where I should run all JUnit tests which written and included to simple .war file.
Is it possible to run all tests via command line using Maven ?
For example: `mvn <.war/.jar file> test`
I am testing Spring Boot application and use maven-surefire-plugin.
My test class included to .war after this:

```
<plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
          <executions>
                <execution>
                <id>generate-test-war</id>
                <phase>test</phase>
           <goals>
                <goal>war</goal>
           </goals>
           </execution>
           </executions>
           <configuration>
                  <warSourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/test/webapp</warSourceDirectory>
                  <warName>${project.artifactId}-test</warName>
                  <webappDirectory>${basedir}/target/${project.artifactId}-test</webappDirectory>
                  <primaryArtifact>false</primaryArtifact>
            <webResources>
            <resource>
                <directory>${basedir}/target/test-classes</directory>
                <targetPath>WEB-INF/classes</targetPath>
            </resource>
            </webResources>
            </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
```

When I unzir .war and run

```
mvn -DTest=<MyTestClass> surefire:test
```

I have got an error with text no test were executed, but test class compiled and has .class extension.

Thank you for your help.